# Storyboard не показывает интерфейс

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

На прототип ячейки в table view добавил button, этот button соединил с другим экраном(view controller), после запуска программы все упало и теперь интерфейс не показывает элементы(Main.storyboard изменился на storyboard)
Попробовал вручную переименовать, в этом случаи программа компилируется успешно, но интерфейс все равно не отображается в xcode
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как вернуть интерфейс? :(

```
<tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="xae-ZQ-e1F" id="e1Q-FJ-p2U">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="51"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" tag="1001" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="z9Z-o6-sHG">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="8" y="-3" width="129" height="56"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" tag="1002" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="WBs-3y-WR0">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="145" y="-3" width="125" height="56"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EuP-u1-yb2">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="253" y="11" width="46" height="30"/>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                <connections>
                                                    <segue destination="jHL-GC-xJZ" kind="showDetail" id="aLo-Tt-myR"/>
                                                </connections>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </tableViewCellContentView>
```

Попытался просто стереть этот кусок кода от 'button' до '/button'>, интерфейса все равно нет, и программа падает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По какойто причине, у Вас не верно отображается storyboard в навигаторе. Возможно вы его случайно переименовали. У Вас отображается как `storyboard`, а это должно быть расширение файла, а не название, переименуйте его в `Main.storyboard`

Comment: попробовал переименовать, компиляйция проходит успешно, но в xcode интерфейс в storyboard не отображается, скриншот добавил

Comment: Нажмите правой кнопкой на Main.storyboard - Opan As - Interface builder Storyboard и посмотрите, что там происходит